# Referencing another namespace in using statement that shares same parent namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, resharper

Lets say we're in class A, which is in namespace `Application.X`, and we have another class B that's in namespace `Application.Y`.

If you want to reference something from class B in class A, which of the following using directive statements is correct (or if both correct, which is preferred):

```cs
using Application.Y;
```

or

```cs
using Y;
```

Comment: This came up as I had been working without ReSharper for a while, and just installed it again. When I opened my project it kept recommending me to use the 2nd example when previously all of mine were like the first one. The code compiles both ways, so both are correct, but I left the question in that structure as I knew it would be more helpful when others come to this question once it's answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, as evidenced by the fact that the code compiles either way and the class found in both cases is the same.

As to which is preferred, the immediate answer is "whatever is specified in your coding standards". If *I* were writing the standards (or just programming for my own sake) I would choose the second because firstly it's shorter to read for the same information, and secondly the extra "Application" in the first option could lead to mild confusion. After all, if you're working in the Application namespace, why did your former self (or a colleague) take the time to specify?

That said, there are people who prefer prefixing uses of class variables with "this" on the theory that it's clearer, and I can easily see some subset of those preferring the first option as it's more explicit.

A final note is that code style tools are there to help you, not the other way around. If you don't like some of the tool's preferences, *especially* if you actually have a
valid argument rather than "that's not how I learned", change them.

Comment: "why did your former self (or a colleague) take the time to specify?" it's a personal project, and as for why? I think Intellisense put it like that when I, for example, would reference an enum from my `Application.Enum` folder/namespace, and it automatically put `using Application.Enum;` at the top.

Comment: Hahahaha I didn't mean that as an actual question to you, it was just a rhetorical you might wonder as you were looking back at it later. VS loves "helping" you to write code in whatever standard you've set. Often this is the Microsoft default, which I personally despise certain aspects of, but what can you do? _Someone's_ gotta create a default.